# Which curves to use for different swaps?

Tags: swaps, pricing

How do we determine which curve to use for pricing different swaps, for e.g. I don't understand how following come:

1. Interest Rate Swap (USD)
   Fixed: USD Treasury
   Floating: none
2. CCS (USDINR)
   Fixed: USD LIBOR
   Floating: USD CBAS IR

Comment: which curve to use for what? For discounting the cash flows? For projecting floating coupons? Something else? Please clarify.

Comment: @DimitriVulis for pricing..edited

Comment: For USD fixed v float - if the float leg resets from 3 months LIBOR, then you use swap curve to project coupons. You use your cost of funding to discount all USD cash flows. I doubt that US treasury is your cost of funding. Perhaps fed funds + some spread? For the cross-currency swap, you still discount USD flows with your cost of funding. You discount the foreign currency cash flows with foreign swap curve (I believe MIBOR for INR) + USDINR cross-currency basis.

Comment: You wrote "which curve to use for pricing". As you probably know, modern pricing techniques use two curve**s**, the projecting curve and discounting curve mentioned in previous comments.